# How to express mathematically the frequency image?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, image-processing, fast-fourier-transform

I have the following frequency square image N x N

[image]

How to express this frequency image in mathematical formulation?

Thanks

Comment: You can check the link about the subject. http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/fourier.htm . Mainly, you can use fast fourier transform for your images as $$F(k,l)=\sum_{m=0}^{N-1} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} f(m,n) e^{-i.2 \pi (\frac{m.k}{N}+\frac{n.l}{N})}$$ Where $f(m,n)$ is your color function and $N$ is your image size.

Comment: what is 'i' stands for?

Comment: $i=\sqrt{-1}$, After the calculation of the sum, you will get real and imaginary values. $F(k,l)=a(k,l)+i. b(k,l)$ format then calculate magnitude and phase. You can focus on magnitude for drawing frequency as image, $|F(k,l)|^2=a^2(k,l)+b^2(k,l)$

Comment: I recommend you have a look the pdf  in the link about 2D fourier transform. http://www.di.univr.it/documenti/OccorrenzaIns/matdid/matdid346761.pdf

Comment: **Thank you, it was helpful**